# Class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveFileFormat$$anon$1 not found while trying to write dataframe to Hive native parquet table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, bigdata

Conf

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet', "true")
```

Hive table

```
spark.sql("create table table_name (ip string, user string) PARTITIONED BY (date date) STORED AS PARQUET")
```

InsertInto

```
df.write.insertInto("table_name", overwrite=True)
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveFileFormat$$anon$1
```

Btw insert into ORC table is good. Running on cluster with client mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is your hive-site.xml file present in the Spark config folder?

Edit:

Can you try with:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("date").saveAsTable("db.table_name")
```

It should not be necessary to set any configuration beforehand and to run the SQL create statement.

Comment: Yes, i have no problems working with Hive, ORC and Text tables, only parquet.

Comment: Sorry for asking, I cannot leave comments yet (low reputation). I am updating my reply, please check soon.

Comment: saveAsTable does not create a table in Hive. Only in spark.

Comment: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html#ki_sparksql_dataframe_saveastable

Comment: I don't know why it works in my case. Please note that the error occurs with Spark version 1.X. I am using Spark 2.4.3